# Poor performance for a clean Apache Cassandra server installation

Tags: performance, cassandra

Just downloaded latest version (2.1.7) of Apache Cassandra from official site.
Then I started the server without any changes on localhost and created table via [GettingStarted Guide](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted)

I noticed, that all queries to the Cassandra server are very slow.
For example, this trivial query takes about 250ms:

> SELECT * FROM users where user_id=1745;

Is it normal performance? I see much better performance for other database systems on the same machine.
May be I should tweak something?

I have:
Intel Core i5 CPU 2.27GHz
8GB RAM
Windows 8.1

**Edit1:**
Well.. I see something strange.
The trace log looks pretty nice (6ms):
[image]

But when I execute this query in DataStax DevStudio, it shows 476ms:
[image]

It cannot be network latency, because I use server on localhost.

Comment: put in query tracing and paste the output

Comment: Also, post your table definition.

Comment: And Windows is not a supported environment for Cassandra.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 I use table from GettingStarted Guilde: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted